# Way to remove two non-consecutive lines in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to remove two non-consecutive lines with a single vim command (which could be undone in a single step).

I have file like this:

```
if (enabled) {
    const a = 1;
    const b = 2;

    console.log(a + b);
}
```

And would like to end up with this:

```
    const a = 1;
    const b = 2;

    console.log(a + b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use visual mode and paste over the whole block.

```
yiBvaBVp
```

[Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Pasting from Visual mode](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/pasting-from-visual-mode/)

For more help see:

```
:h iB
:h aB
:h v_p
```

Answer (score 1):

If you select your example (with `v$%` for instance), then

```
:'<,'>g/{\|}/d
```

will give you what you want (if there are no nested `{` or `}`).

---

Another way would be to record a macro, something like

```
# qa to start recording, the final q to stop. ^O is <Ctrl-o>
qaf{%dd^Oddq
```

then use it with @a.

---

**Edit**: more general solution (still using visual mode though):

You could add a mapping:

```
:xnoremap <leader>d <esc>:'<d \| '>d<cr>
```

to delete the first and last line of the last visual selection.

Comment: I was looking for a general way, which would work on other type of files, like HTML.

Comment: Well the macro could be made to work on things vim sees as pairs (which would work for html as long as you load `matchit.vim`, which (I believe) most vim distributions include). Added another more general way using visual mode.